# angularjs - get controller function and pass it to $injector.invoke()

Tags: angularjs, controller

I had two controllers which were defined like this:

```
function ControllerA(DependencyA, DependencyB) {
    // code
}

function ControllerB(DependencyC, DependencyD) {
    // code
    $injector.invoke(ControllerA);
}
```

However, in order to support minification, I modified controller definitions:

```
myApp.controller('controllerA', ['DependencyA', 'DependencyB' 
    function (DependencyA, DependencyB) {
    // code
}]);


myApp.controller('controllerB', ['DependencyC', 'DependencyD']
    function (DependencyC, DependencyD) {
        // $injector.invoke(controllerA) // ReferenceError: controllerA is not defined 
}]);
```

The problem is that $injector.invoke() expects a **function** as a parameter, so the question is how can controllerA be passed to $injector.invoke()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To instantiate a controller you can use the `$controller`service, which can be called with a string:

```
$controller('controllerA' /*, locals */);
```